# Can "Controller" be used within an MVC controller name

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, controller, naming-conventions

Because all Controllers in MVC are suffixed by "Controller" Would it be OK to name my controller LocalControllerController?

Would this be flouting or breaking any MVC naming rules?

Would calling my controller "LocalController" in helpers like @Url.Action("Index", "LocalController") give rise to any issues?

Comment: I don't know, if it's valid for mvc, but this is not a very good design to use at all

Comment: In my domain, the entity is called a LocalController, I know I can try to substitute "Controller" for another word, but it wouldn't make much sense

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but you might run into an issue with routing.

Also, your MVC controllers names don't necessarily have to match up with your domain entity names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be fine from technical point of view.

Readability of code with such class name is questionable and confusing from my point of view, but it is subjective and you need to decide yourself.